# adding wakelock on fragment not working highlights red

Tags: java, android

I am using fragment so not sure why this is not working

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

the  `getwindow` is highlighted red
cannot resolve method getwindow

Comment: forget about `getActivity` ? try like 
`getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a fragment you should use getActivity() method to access the getWindow() method. Following will help you:

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```